# How to create exe of a web application in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to create an exe of an website created in asp.net using visual studio 2010.
I don't known whether exe of web application can be created or not, but I want that my application with database will be able to run on another system where visual studio will or will not be there.And my code should not to be visible to the users using that exe or running that project.
How can I achieve it?!

Comment: Problem 1: ASP.net websites require a webserver to run. Problem 2: Any Code? Do you include HTML/CSS/Javascript in this requirement.... the list goes on.

Comment: exe of **WEB APP** ?? i dont think so it is possible. If you want to access your app to other system then you can deploy it on local IIS and  use from different sysetm with ip address .It will not show any kind of code to user (client). Facebook is also a WEB APP so have u seen any code of it yet? :P

Comment: I think first you should study about the web application web sites ,asp.net,IIS etc

Comment: I did'nt get your point.Can you please elaborate it Jon P

Comment: Host that application in IIS to that location, you cannot create an exe of web application.

Comment: I have hosted my application in IIS,now what?

Comment: Do you know what is a website?

Answer (score 0):

you can't make a exe for web application but you can do one thing to solve your problem

1)make a window project in this project make a code for run iis and open browser with your web application url  and make your window application form hide

2) now make exe of your window application project

Comment: I dont want to make a windows application, I am working on a website.
Do I need to publish the website through iis,if yes then how?
And after that how it will be able to run on other systems.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an executable file in asp.net.

All you can do is create a website using visual studio. once done, publish your website. Deploy it to IIS or host it to a paid web hosting company so you can have your domain. Once done, other users can see your beautiful and elegant website.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create exe of a web application. It is hosted on IIS. So first of all you have to publish your website and then you can host it. For more information you can refer to this one:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx Or google for more articles.

Comment: But after the site is published through IIS database is not able to be attached with it.How would it be done?

Comment: Have you updated your configuration file? Please check your configuration in web.config in case your production database is different than database you used during development.

Answer (score 0):

Posting to an old thread, but I came across this situation and found the solution.
Following footsteps of Spring Boot and other containerized solutions, I believe now Microsoft also has added this feature.

**My scenario**: Created a basic **REST based Web application** and built it.
This created Debug and Release folder within \bin within the root directory of Web application.

It also creates an exe file.

You **just need the necessary runtime dependencies** (like .NetCore 3.1 etc in my case) to run this exe.

I copied the entire Web application folder to a Windows Server 2016. There were some issues initially, however later when I added the required dependencies (dotnet folder which was present in my earlier machine), it worked like a charm.